# What are the differences between following two javascript code?

Tags: javascript, function

In some Javascript code which uses immediate function, it has argument `window` or `document` like the following:

```
(function (window, document) {
  ...
})(window, document);
```

However, `window` and `document` are global objects and can be directly accessed as follow:

```
(function () {
  var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  ...
  var el = document.getElementById(...)
  ...
})();
```

What are the differences between the above two codes. Which is better way and why?

Comment: Doing so allows you to modify the actual values of `window` and `document` within that scope; e.g. things are different for Node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons I can think of:

1) Local variables are the first in the scope chain, so their access is faster than globals *(with faster I mean insignificantly faster)*.

2) Inside the function, `window` and `document` are local variables, so their names can be minimified:

```
(function (w, d) {
//var userAgent = w.navigator.userAgent;

)(window, document);
```

Answer (score 4):

> What are the differences between the above two codes. Which is better way and why?

In all practicality and usage in browsers only, there's no appreciable difference.

That said, there's a very slight performance increase that comes from referencing local variables instead of globals.

Also, it allows the flexibility of swapping out the real `window` by a mock version; this could be useful during testing and in certain environments where some of the objects are not available and must be replaced.

Btw, there's another kind of argument you could pass, which is `undefined`; it goes like this:

```
(function(undefined) {
    // your code
}());
```

You don't actually pass anything to the outer function and by doing so you make sure that `undefined` has not been tampered with; pedantic people like myself would just `void 0` for that purpose though :)

Answer (score -1):

The difference is polymorphism: in the first case, you could pass the function any pair of objects that behave as the `window` and the `document` objects (at least for the methods your function calls), and the function will work too with them.

In practice, with this two objects in particular, it's more error prone that any benefit - everyone expects `window` and `document` to be *the* `window` and `document` defined by Javascript. But in theory, that's the gain.

Comment: *“it's more error prone”* I don't understand why that should be. It seems more robust to me: if you run the script in an environment that doesn't have `window`, you can swap it out by modifying only one line. Duck typing is a feature of dynamically-typed languages, not a weakness.

Comment: Provided one expects `window` and `document` to be _those_ `window` and `document` we all know, having a relatively large function with those variables redefined can lead to mistakes by quick patching a function or the like. They're not constants, but one expects them to behave like that. I would call them with a different name - that's my point.